# Using android device as display for GNU screen

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, android, gnu-screen, xrandr

The idea is to attach my Android device as additional display to extend the workspace. So far I've tried VNC and Splashtop, but none of them is responsive enough to use daily.

I figured, I could use GNU screen and SSH client on the android device, and have this as a dedicated display only for CLI programs. The performance is superb.

I need to be able to switch this GNU screen window, without seeing it on the primary display. I figured it could live in invisible X space, so I've extended the desktop using `xrandr --fb`. But now, whenever I move my cursor to the right, the screen goes with it.

Is there a way to have this terminal window outside of the screen, and not be forced to see it on the primary display? Or, is there a better way of attaching android device as terminal-only display?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: hope this help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display best regards